# почему не все c++ библиотеки header-only?

Tags: c++

Почему не все c++ библиотеки header-only?
Даже Boost предоставляет часть функционала в виде header-only библиотек, а часть в виде скомпилированных.
И возникает 2 вопроса:

1. Есть ли какие то ограничения у header-only библиотек?
2. Какой тип и когда лучше использовать?

Comment: Не стану писать это в ответ, ибо не полный, но: header-only делают библиотеки с открытыми исходниками, насколько мне известно. Если же автор библиотеки хочет сохранить реализацию функционала в секрете от пользователя, он делает статическую/динамическую либу, из которой нельзя получить исходный код. Насчёт boost точно не знаю, возможно, они оставили не header-only те фичи, которыми "особенно дорожат".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11363011/13970074

Comment: вообще-то в Си++ курс на отмену заголовочников, вот в Си++20 будут [модули](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules)

Comment: Иногда требуется вызывать код на другом языке программирования. header-only эту задачу решить не может, нужен компоновщик.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему не все c++ библиотеки являются header-only, можно понять, рассмотрев их плюсы и минусы

---

Плюсы использования header-only библиотек:

1. Позволяют упростить доставку библиотек для клиента, так как клиент сам сможет скомпилировать для себя исходный файл с нужными настройками под нужную платформу.
2. Позволяет компилятору делать больше оптимизаций, в частности inline, что невозможно при разделении библиотек на файлы реализации и интерфейса, но вы подвергаетесь риску раздувания исполняемого кода из-за использования этого заголовочного файла во многих единицах трансляции, но большинство компиляторов умны и могут избегать этого.
3. При добавлении header-only в проект требуется только include-paths.

---

Недостатки использования header-only библиотек:

1. Вы не можете скрыть детали реализации, как этого можно добиться при разделении библиотеки на интерфейс в виде `.h` файла и файла реализации поставляемого например в виде `.lib`, `.dll`.
2. Большинство изменений в библиотеке потребует перекомпиляции всех единиц компиляции, использующих эту библиотеку.
3. Более длительное время компиляции, так как  компилятор должен видеть реализацию всех компонентов во включенных файлах, а не только их интерфейсы.
4. усложняется чтение кода, так как клиенту проще видеть только интерфейс используемого функционала и не отвлекаться на реализацию (спорное утверждение).
5. Нельзя слинковать динамически = нельзя заменить/обновить библиотеку в уже скомпилированной программе.

---

Когда от использования header-only библиотек ни куда не деться:

1. При использовании шаблонов (`template`) включение определений в заголовок является единственным способом компиляции (если явного инстанцирования шаблонов недостаточно), так как компилятор должен знать полное определение шаблонов, чтобы инстанцировать шаблон.

---

Исходя из всего вышесказанного каждый может сделать для себя вывод, использовать header-only или нет, я же считаю, что использование header-only библиотеки не самое лучшее решение в большинстве случаев, если вам только не требуются шаблоны или inline функции.

Comment: (5) Нельзя слинковать динамически = нельзя заменить/обновить библиотеку в уже скомпилированной программе.

Comment: *при использовании шаблонов (`template`) включение определений в заголовок является единственным способом компиляции* — а как же явное инстанцирование? *из этого всего можно сделать вывод, что использование header-only библиотеки не самое лучшее решение* — вы не привели плюсы, то есть делаете вывод только по минусам

Comment: 6 пункт не имеет отношения к header-only библиотекам.

Comment: ага, 6 пункт удалили:) теперь возьмемся за пятый. Он также не имеет прямого отношения header-only. Если есть не header-only библиотека (к примеру, там один h и один cpp файл), то заменить ее в уже скомпилированом приложении немного сложновато.
пункт 4 также не имеет отношения. В правильно организованной header-only библиотеке все чисто и красиво. Плюс, документация сильно может все улучшить.

Comment: @KoVadim 4 пункт мне кажется спорный, так как некоторые все-таки предпочитают естественное разделение на интерфейс и реализацию, чтобы не копаться в одном файле и документация не всегда есть или не так хороша; 5 пункт предлагаете совсем убрать? или все таки можно как то исправить?

Comment: @KoVadim можете посоветовать, что и где можно почитать на счет 6 пункта, убрал его так не совсем была уверенность в нём

Comment: 6 пункт - тут вообще к коду относится, 5 пункт относится больше к dll/so. 4 - пункт - те же хедеры можно аккуратно и красиво разделить.
по поводу всего ответа - он как по мне странный. Отличий то всего пара - не все можно сделать в header-only библиоткеках, но стандарт языка поправляют (те же inline переменные) и все меньше и меньше препятствий. Второе - программисты любят header-only библиотеки - просто подключил и готово.

Answer (score 1):

Плюсы header-only библиотек фактически сводятся только к удобству их использования.
И программистам они очень нравятся. А вот для конечного продукта - это довольно спорная возможность языка.

Думаю многие заметили как разбух исполняемый код многих программ. Зачастую он измеряется гигабайтами, и с каждой новой версией программного продукта чуть ли не удваивается, хотя приращение функционала практически не замечается (в основном меняется дизайн интерфейса для маркетинговых целей).

Причина неимоверного разбухания исполняемого кода кроется именно в header-only библиотеках.

Хотя компилятор и не включает повторный header код (#ifndef ... #define ...), но это происходит только для единицы компиляции, т.е. для объектного файла. Но каждый исполняемый файл (.exe, .dll, ...) линкуется из множества объектных файлов. Программный продукт бывает состоит из тысяч исполняемых. Т.е. происходит много-тысячное дублирование кода.